# using badge with bootstrap 4 in asp.net core 3.1 asynchronous programing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-3.1, badge

I have used badge in asp.net core 3.1 without Async method this is my code in service

```
 public int GetNotSeenContact()
    {
        return _context.Contacts.Where(s => s.Seen == false).Count();
    }
```

and this is call in scope layout :

```
 public int GetContactCont()
    {
        return _admin.GetNotSeenContact();
    }
```

and this is the place that I use this:

```
 int ConactBell = scope.GetContactCont();
```

and this is my html code that I called :

```
 <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning notification">@ConactBell</span>
```

this is working very well but when I make it with Async method, it shows this exception instead of number for user:

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Int32,DIG.Core.Classes.PanelLayoutScope+&lt;GetContactCont&gt;d__3]
```

Now these are my codes in async method in service:

```
 public async Task<int> GetNotSeenContact()
    {
        return await _context.Contacts.Where(s => s.Seen == false).CountAsync();
    }
```

this is in my scope class:

```
 public async Task<int> GetContactCont()
    {
        return await _admin.GetNotSeenContact();
    }
```

and this is the code where I use it inside html code:

```
@inject PanelLayoutScope scope
@{
Task<int> ConactBell = scope.GetContactCont();}
```

my html code :

```
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning notification">@ConactBell</span>
```

Please give me the best solution and tell me why does this happen when I use Async method. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's controller code. Don't put it in the view. That breaks how the MVC pattern works - the controller does the heavy lifting and produces a viewmodel/bag of data that's displayed by the view. A view doesn't support async code because it *doesn't need it* - the data should already be available

Comment: Even if you use the newer Razor Pages model, the *view* should never execute data access code. That's what the Controller (in MVC) or the PageModel (in Razor Pages) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the method is asynchronous,you can try to use await.Change

```
@{
Task<int> ConactBell = scope.GetContactCont();}
```

to

```
@{
    var ConactBell =await scope.GetContactCont();}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: But as `Panagiotis Kanavos` said,we do not execute data access code in view.